# Were gfci's required in detached garage built in 2003?

Tags: electrical

Need info if gfci's were required in detached garage built in 2003.

Comment: I believe this is going to depend on your local building codes.

Comment: Where in the world are you?

Comment: ... and have you seen Carmen Sandiego recently?

Answer (score 4):

GFCI's in garages have been required for a lot longer than 2003 according to the National Electrical Code.

From NEC 1999:

> 210-8 Ground-Fault Circuit-Interrupter Protection for
>   Personnel
>
> (A)(2) Garages, and also accessory buildings that have a floor
>   located at or below grade level not intended as habitable rooms and limited to storage areas, work areas, and areas of similar use.

The 2002 Code says the same thing in the same section.

If the garage was built in 2003 it should have had GFCI protection installed for all receptacles.